# Vercel - What happens if I disconnect my Git repository?

Tags: github, gitlab, vercel

I work at a company and the IT department decided to migrate every repository from GitLab to GitHub. Now I need to change the Git repository on Vercel to connect to GitHub repo instead of GitLab.

My question is: what happens when I disconnect the GitLab repo on Vercel? Does the website goes offline? Or does it stays up while I connect to the GitHub repo and rebuilds?

I haven't tried anything yet because if the website goes offline it would cause a lot of trouble at the company.

Comment: I've never used Vercel, but I'd be surprised if simply changing your Git URL broke anything. I suspect nothing will happen until your next build.

Answer (score 0):

No, the website does not go offline.

Also, after connecting your new repository will stay as is until you push to your production branch (master/main...).